# How to nest ids in SCSS?

Tags: php, html, sass

I am trying to apply a `function` to an `id` and nest them inside an element.

Basically I want to nest this (which works):

```
element#idname .functionname {...}
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
element {
  #idname.functionname {...}
}
```

I've played around with `&` and `spaces` without success. Is it even possible? I can't find anything on nesting `ids` in `SCSS/SASS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code should provide expected output

```
element {
  &#idname .functionname { color: tomato; }
}
```

Output

```
element#idname .functionname {
  color: tomato;
}
```

you can try by yourself on this online compiler: https://www.sassmeister.com/